# Django 'Cannot add foreign key constraint' error while doing makemigrations operation

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django 1.9.5 and python 2.7. I am also using MySQL as db.
When i try to make migrations i get below error

> "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

I get this error as i am trying to add many to many field to an existing table.
When i make migration and migrate, the many to many relation table is created but
without foreign key constraint.

While runserver it also says;

> "You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied."

Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
I can add new data to this table ,but without foreign key constraint, through the web site.
But i need the table fields to be created with foreignkey constraint for the relations.
The operation will create many to many relation between Worker and Workerduty tables.
MySQL is InnoDB configured.

Error Logs :

```
        # python manage.py migrate
    Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: authtoken, sessions, admin, auth, reversion, contenttypes, company
    Running migrations:
      Rendering model states... DONE
      Applying company.0005_Worker_duty_type...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
        self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 90, in __exit__
        self.execute(sql)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "/home/dataproj/Env/dataproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

Codes are below :

```
models.py :


class Workerduty(BaseModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Worker Duty"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Worker(BaseModel):

    duty_type = models.ManyToManyField(Workerduty, verbose_name=_("Worker Duty"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("Workerl", _("Workerl")),
        )
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.name.title()
        grps = []
        for Workerduty_obj in self.Workerduty.all():
            grp = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=Workerduty_obj.name)[0]
            grps.append(grp)
        self.user.grps = grps
        self.user.save()
        super(Worker, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Migration File :

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.5 on 2018-06-28 20:09
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('company', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Workerduty',
            fields=[
                ('uuid', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='Unique Identifier')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Worker Duty')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['name'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='worker',
            name='worker_type',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='college.Workerduty', verbose_name='Worker Duty'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant migration file?

Comment: I added migration file to the post

Comment: So you used an UUID as primary key? I think using CharFields as primary key is problematic, since equality of strings is typically a hard problem in the database world. You should check the collation settings.

Comment: See for example here: https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439

Comment: Actually i didnt set it as primary key. This is dynamically created migration file, and i didnt touch it. The uuid field is put and set as primary key by django.

Comment: well django does not set primary keys itself. It is probably in the `BaseModel`that you specify this as primary key.

Comment: I am new to Django and trying to work on an existing project. Do you mean below code ? class BaseModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, verbose_name=_("Unique Identifier"))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

Comment: Should i make it False ?

Comment: I set it to False. But still getting django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint') error

Comment: Also if i set uuid=false, django creates an id field with primary_key=true in migration file. But i dont need an id field.

Comment: well you first need to remove the migration file, make new migrations, and then run them. Since now you are still stuck at *this* migration./

Comment: I did it again but still same problem. As i understand in the DB the foreign key fields cannot be set as UNIQUE.
Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: the foreign keys *can* be set as unique. In fact this is in Django known as a `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Ok but i have a smilar table structure in another project and it is working. A row in Worker table can match multiple tables in Workerduty table. So this is done with a middle table that is created by Django. This middle table is Worker_duty_type. And this Worker_duty_type should have rows composed of other two table  uuids columns as foreign keys. The colums are created successfully in middle table but they cannot be set as foreign key. So relation cannot be get.

Comment: yes, but as said before, this is due to the *collation* of the database. The target table has different collation, than the referencing one. Since Django does not handle collation at all, you are now going to experience the nice world of collations in a database environment (and this will be all but funny) :s

Comment: I think below command fails at the background on mysql. CONSTRAINT `company__worker_worker_id_d949_fk_company_workerduty_uuid` FOREIGN KEY (`workerduty_id`) REFERENCES `company_workerduty` (`uuid`)

Comment: exactly. And if you will query for `desc company_workerduty`, and `company_workertype` you will see that this is because the collation of the two columns is different.

Comment: Perfect. I found that original table is utf8 but newly created is latin1. How can i force django to create table and rows with utf8 ?

Comment: that's what I already have tried to tell you: Django does not know anything about collation. So you will have a nice time figuring out how to change the collation of the other table... :(

Comment: I understand you. But problem is this. There is an existing workers model table which is utf8 collation. Then i create workersduty model table. This new created table is latin1. Ok. Then i change this new created workersduty table to utf8 manually.  Now i have 2 tables with utf8 collation. If i need to connect these 2 tables with manytomany field. A third table is created by Django. This newly created table is not created by a class model written by me. It is generated by django to keep foreign keys. This new db is also created with latin1 collation. So django must create it with utf8.

Comment: Thank you so much Willem Van Onsem. Problem is solved. I changed whole MySQL db colletion to utf8 and now foreign keys are created. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : I was working on an existing project. The MySQL DB was UTF8 collated.
I prepared a test environment with a new MySQL and cloned the DB.
But the default mysql collation was Latin1 while imported DB was UTF8.
So there was a conflict between old tables and newly created tables by django.
So i changed the new mysql installation's collation to utf8. So newly created tables are now created with new default utf8 collation which is same with imported DB.

I used below command on mysql console :

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat('ALTER DATABASE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA like  'DbName';
```